# Can I replay quests in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Am I able to replay quests multiple times in Borderlands 2?

I know I can fight bosses again if I want to farm their gear. Would I be able to do this if I want to farm rewards from quests too?

If replaying/farming quests is possible is it performed via the same way boss fights can be farmed - exiting and reloading the world?

Comment: Related: [Are quest rewards the same on subsequent playthroughs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87649/4797) | [Borderlands 2 drop/quest rewards at non-max levels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255565/4797)

Answer (score 3):

Are you farming for quest rewards? Then, no. Once it completes, it completes for you. Only one reward per quest per play through.

You can run the quest again if someone else hosts the game and runs the quest (assuming they haven't completed it yet) but at the end of the quest, the game will tell you that you already have accepted the quest reward and won't give you another. (Your friend will still get the reward, but then they've completed it so they can't again, without another friend...)

If you're farming general item or boss drops that spit out on the ground for pickup, then you can by the above "friends' game" method.

Obviously, this is all for non-repeatable quests. For repeatable quests (they're marked in the quest log as such) they're, well, repeatable. So no issues there.

Comment: Thanks. How would I repeat repeatable quests do I go back to who assigned them or is it in the quest log

Comment: There are only a few, usually for end game raid bosses like Pyro Pete. You usually go back to the mission giver to get it again, if it's one of the few that are possible. It does not stick around in the log. (Except usually the first completed version in your Completed section; but not the follow-up repeatable version which will only show once you've picked it up again.)